# GitHub Actions YAML for multiple deployment images for different stages with the same pipeline

Tags: github, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I am working on a GitHub Actions Pipeline for the deployment of different images for a different environment, but I have been getting a "bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 72, column 5:" for this YAML, where I am trying to set prod variables, I have tried every which way but I am not sure what might be wrong here, please help me out.

```
   name: 'Manual - Build & Deploy - Enterprise'
    
    on:
      push:
        branches-ignore:
          - '**'
    
      workflow_dispatch:
        inputs:
          git-ref:
            description: Git Ref (Optional)
            default: develop
            required: false
    
          account:
            description: slb-dev, slb-prod
            default: slb-dev
            required: true
            
          account_prod:
           description: slb-dev, slb-prod
           default: slb-prod
           required: true
    
          environment:
            description: development (main, int, qs), production (v1_demo, v1_rosecity, demo)
            default: main
            required: false
    
          microservice:
            description: chroma, liquid, tenant, dashboard, lims, lims-simulator, client, logging, metrc
            default: chroma
            required: false
    
          builddir:
            description: MicroChromatographyService/MicroChromatographyService, MicroLiquidHandlingService/MicroLiquidHandlingService, MicroTenantService/MicroTenantService, MicroDashboardService/MicroDashboardService, LIMSIntegrationService/LIMSIntegrationService, LIMSSimulatorService/LIMSSimulatorService, IntegrationHubClientService/IntegrationHubClientService, PerkinElmer.LoggingService/PerkinElmer.LoggingService, MetRCReportService/MetRCReportService
            default: MicroChromatographyService/MicroChromatographyService
            required: false
    
    jobs:
      setup:
        name: Setup ENV Variables
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        environment:
         name: dev
         url: https://dev.test.com
        steps:
        - name: Set Vars
          id: setvars
          run: |
              echo "::set-output name=APP_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=AWS_REGION::us-east-1"
              echo "::set-output name=SHA8::${{ github.sha }} | cut -c1-8)"
              echo "::set-output name=BUILD_DIR::${{ github.event.inputs.builddir }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECR_REPOSITORY::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_CLUSTER::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_SERVICE::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE::task-definition-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}.json"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_CONTAINER_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
        outputs:
          APP_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.APP_NAME }}
          AWS_REGION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
          SHA8: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.SHA8 }}
          BUILD_DIR: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
          ECS_CLUSTER: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          ECS_SERVICE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
          ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
          ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
          ECS_CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}

        - name: Set Prod Vars
          id: setprodvars
          run: |
              echo "::set-output name=APP_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=AWS_REGION::us-east-1"
              echo "::set-output name=SHA8::${{ github.sha }} | cut -c1-8)"
              echo "::set-output name=BUILD_DIR::${{ github.event.inputs.builddir }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECR_REPOSITORY::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_CLUSTER::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_SERVICE::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE::task-definition-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}.json"
              echo "::set-output name=ECS_CONTAINER_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.account_prod }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
        outputs:
          APP_NAME: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.APP_NAME }}
          AWS_REGION: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
          SHA8: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.SHA8 }}
          BUILD_DIR: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
          ECS_CLUSTER: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          ECS_SERVICE: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
          ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
          ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
          ECS_CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ steps.setprodvars.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
          
      DeployDev:
        name: Deploy to Dev 
        needs: setup
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions:
         packages: write
         contents: write
         id-token: write
        environment: 
          name: Dev
          url: 'http://dev.myapp.com'
        steps:
        - name: Set Environments
          run: |
            if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-dev" ]]; then
              echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
              echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            fi
    
            if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-prod" ]]; then
              echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
              echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            fi
    
        - name: Clone Repository (Current branch)
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
          if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''
    
        - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
          if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
          with:
            ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}
    
        - name: Configure AWS credentials
          uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
          with:
            aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}         
            aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} 
            aws-region: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
    
        - name: Login to Amazon ECR
          id: login-ecr
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
    
        - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
          id: build-image
          env:
            ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
            ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
            IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
          run: |
            cd ${{ needs.setup.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
            docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
            docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
            docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
            echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
    
        - name: Download task definition
          run: |
            aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }} --query taskDefinition > ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
    
        - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
          id: task-def
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
          with:
            task-definition: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
            container-name: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
            image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}
    
        - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
          with:
            task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
            service: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
            cluster: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
            wait-for-service-stability: true
    
    
      DeployProd:
        name: Deploy to Production 
        needs: [setup, DeployDev]
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions:
         packages: write
         contents: write
         id-token: write
        environment: 
          name: Production
          url: 'http://dev.myapp.com'
        steps:
        - name: Set Environments
          run: |
            if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account_prod}}" == "slb-dev" ]]; then
              echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
              echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            fi
            if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account_prod}}" == "slb-prod" ]]; then
              echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
              echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            fi
        - name: Clone Repository (Current branch)
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
          if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''
    
        - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
          if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
          with:
            ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}
    
        - name: Configure AWS credentials
          uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
          with:
            aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}         
            aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} 
            aws-region: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
    
        - name: Login to Amazon ECR
          id: login-ecr
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
    
        - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
          id: build-image
          env:
            ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
            ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
            IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
          run: |
            cd ${{ needs.setup.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
            docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
            docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
            docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
            echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
        - name: Download task definition
          run: |
            aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }} --query taskDefinition > ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
        - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
          id: task-def
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
          with:
            task-definition: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
            container-name: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
            image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}
    
        - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
          uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
          with:
            task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
            service: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
            cluster: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
            wait-for-service-stability: true
```

Comment: When you try editing the yaml file directly and the Github site (User Interface), it generally indicates those indentation or syntax errors "live" for you to correct them before committing. Did you try it? 

Comment: Yeah, I gave that a shot too and got the same error.

Comment: For what I checked here (finally had access to a computer), the problem seems to be on the `setup` job. Your set 2 `outputs` fields for this job, with the same output names, but related to different steps (`Set Vars` and `Set Prod Vars`). I separated them into 2 different jobs and it resolved the workflow error: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester20.yml (I also updated the needs job for the subsequent jobs and outputs)

Comment: That worked, thanks a ton mate

Comment: Great. I'll add as official answer then 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I checked here, the problem is on your `setup` job. You set 2 `outputs` fields for this job, with the same output names, but related to different steps (`Set Vars` and `Set Prod Vars`).

*You can't have more than o e `output` field per job.*

I separated them into 2 different jobs and it resolved the workflow error. You can check the final implementation [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester20.yml) .

*Note that I also updated the `needs jobs` for the subsequent jobs and outputs so it should work as expected.*